# MySQL NET Connect 6.7.2 in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I have installed the MySQL NET Connector 6.7.2 and am currently unable to get Visual Studio 2012 to recognize that the connector is installed. Is there a trick to this with the beta connector?

I see in that in the MySQL developer blog there is a mention of a separation of utility for Visual Studio integration starting in 6.7.X releases for the connector.

[MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.2 Beta has been released](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_connector_net_6_72?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=mysql-connectornet-6-7-2-beta-has-been-released)

Am I missing a second utility to make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows (see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html).

PS. Close VS before installation.

If you have installed any MySql products you should choose Add Products or something simialar in the Installer.