# MySQL Connector for Visual Studio 2012 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, datasource, mysql-connector

since I've installed mysql connector 6.7.4 and Update 3 for Visual Studio 2012 the MySQL Connector is gone away from the Connection Manager dialog.

It was a working project, so the data source configuration is correct. But when I open my existing *.edmx file I get an error (see the picture below).

I've tried to reinstall the connector with rebooting between each installation step, controlled the GAC but I cannot get the connector working back again.

I believe it is related to the Update 3, as mentioned in the comment of the answer post here: [mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)

I'm not able to read Portuguese so I don't know if there is already a solution for this problem.

Does somebody have the same issue or does somebody know a solution?

Best regards
Felix

[image: Missing connector in the datasource dialog]

[image: Errors in the EDMX file]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is very easy...

Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio available using the MySQL Installer for Windows (see http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html).

Reference: [MySQL NET Connect 6.7.2 in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346822/mysql-net-connect-6-7-2-in-visual-studio-2012?rq=1)

Too bad that I did not found any documentation about this on the MySQL Website.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. What tooling support is being provided for VS2013, if any?

Comment: @JasCav: see the answer comments above for information about VS2013 integration

Answer (score 10):

The new version of MySQL installer 5.6.14 contains the support for Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 and you can get it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

The below images show how to install that support since by default is not activated

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. Do you know something about integration to VS2013?

Comment: For now I have read that the support is untill VS2012 only. About VS2013 I have not any data

Comment: VS2013 support was added in MySql for visual Studio 1.1, available at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/