# Is there a way to get MySQL to work with Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a Windows 7, 64 bit computer.

My Visual Studio is: VS Express for Desktop 2012.
I have MySQL Server 5.6.15.
I've tried Installer 5.5 and 5.6
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

I believe I have .NET 4.5

I have tried MySQL Connectors/Net (6.74, 6.66, 6.57, 6.16.)
[image]

But I can't get access to MySQL through VS 2012 Express (or 2013 for that matter). (See below)

[image]

This is my Visual Studio.

[image]

I've tried all these:

[MySQL Data Source not appearing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879451/mysql-data-source-not-appearing-in-visual-studio/17774997#17774997)

[How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235291/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-data-source-in-visual-studio?rq=1)

[MySQL Connector for Visual Studio 2012 Update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806294/mysql-connector-for-visual-studio-2012-update-3)

[MySQL NET Connect 6.7.2 in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346822/mysql-net-connect-6-7-2-in-visual-studio-2012?rq=1)

[mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)

[MySQL For Visual Studio 2012/2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664663/mysql-for-visual-studio-2012-2013)

None have worked. Is it my Visual Studio?

With all the trial and error with the Connector/NET it would seem it's perhaps my Visual Studio Express Edition? Do I need 2010? Really hate losing all the features (I typically use 2013, but want to be able to connect to MySQL for a few learning projects).

[image]

EDIT: I think it is the Visual Studio edition, specifically, "Express" even though the add-ons I upload say it works for Visual Studio 2008, 2010, and 2012...I think it is only for the full editions.

If you've somehow gotten Express to work with MySQL, I'd love to know you're configuration.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting? have you checked if you are able to connect to the mysql server by other means (`telnet` at least) from the machine you  are using VS? MySQL server connection is host based (NOT just user name/password - username - password @host)

Comment: its not available in express edition

Comment: @bansi, I'm not getting an error message. I can run workbench and query the MySQL database just fine. I'm thinking perhaps I didn't register 2012?

I can't even find Visual Studio 2012 Express on the Microsoft Website anymore. Wondering if there's no more support for it to MySQL...

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2

Comment: I never had any problems with MySQL connector with VS. May be because I never use the installers. I just down the zip for `.Net & Mono` un-compress it and refer the required `mysql.data.dll` you won't get VS integration (may be i don't trust VS much on this) but you can code `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`.

Answer (score 3):

I found this on the MySQL page - I'm posting it as an answer as there's about 6 other posts that seem to have a similar issue. IF someone is able to get Express edition(s) to work with MySQL (if somehow possible) - that would be the best answer.

Otherwise, this may be helpful to others.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,546265,564533#msg-564533

[image]

Comment: This really is the best answer. IMO stackoverflow should not provide a workaround, if one exists, to bypass "legal constraints."